problems in making predictor matrix in r for mcglm model
I am doing mcglm model for retinopathy(factor, yes, no) and set of 450 proteins (x), age, sex, bmi as predictor.
i am getting following error while making predictor matrix.
Z1 <- mc_mixed(ret~x+bmi+age+sex,data=df)> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
 error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'forceSymmetric': non-conformable arguments 

It would be appreciated if you can provide me r code for how to resolve this issue.
Thanks!
